# Did Voldemort Use Fiendfyre Against Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Did Voldemort use Fiendfyre against Dumbledore during their duel at the end of *Order of the Phoenix* in the Ministry of Magic? Here's the specific passage I'm wondering about:

> A long thin flame flew from the tip [of Dumbledore's wand]; it wrapped itself around Voldemort, shield and all. For a moment, it seemed Dumbledore had won, **but then the fiery rope became a serpent**, which relinquished its hold on Voldemort at once and turned, **hissing furiously**, to face Dumbledore.
>   Voldemort vanished; **the snake reared from the floor, ready to strike** –
>   There was a burst of flame in midair above Dumbledore just as Voldemort reappeared, standing on the plinth in the middle of the pool where so recently the five statues had stood.
>   ‘Look out!’ Harry yelled.
>   But even as he shouted, another jet of green light flew at Dumbledore from Voldemort’s wand and **the snake struck** –
>   *Order of the Phoenix* - pages 718-719 - chapter 36, *The Only One He Ever Feared*

Crabbe set the Room of Requirement on fire using Fiendfyre and ended up dying as a result because he didn't know how to control the fire. Two wizards as powerful as Dumbledore and Voldemort would be able to control Fiendfyre well enough to use it in a duel, I believe. However, we only see a snake form from whatever type of fire Dumbledore conjured, and not multiple creatures like how Fiendfyre presented in the Room of Requirement. But again, that could go back to Crabbe not knowing how to control it. **Is the fire used in Dumbledore and Voldemort's Ministry of Magic duel Fiendfyre, or is it some other kind of magical fire?**

Comment: Can't find any canon or JKR info on this. Someone needs to contact JKR to answer this one :)

Comment: I read that as some sort of transmutation into a physical snake, not a snake made of fire.

Comment: @Izkata That's how I read it too, though I know the movie shows him creating a fiery snake. IMO if JKR was intending for it to be Fiendfyre it would be less ambiguous.

Comment: I bet JKR hadn't come up with the fiend fire concept before writing book seven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the harry potter wikia:

> Fiendfyre is a type of fire made from **Dark Magic**.

The spell originated from Dumbledore, who is admittedly a powerful wizard, he is not a Dark Magic user. Also I don't think that you could change the type of spell you are redirecting (from spell to curse).

Even so, Fiendfyre is living fire, and thus the form of a rope doesn't fit with the normal shape of the curse. Only when V turns it against Dumbledore does it even look like it might be Fiendfyre.

Comment: I like your point about Dumbledore not being a Dark Wizard. :)

Comment: Can you provide a *canon* source that Fiendfyre involves Dark Magic?